# Using Cauchy's Criterion to show non-uniform convergence of series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I want to show $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$$$x\in(-1,1)$$ does not converge uniformly using the negation of Cauchy's Criterion for uniform convergence of series of functions.

Cauchy's Criterion states that $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly iff $$\forall \epsilon>0\text{ }\exists l\in N\text{ }\forall x\in D\text{ }\forall m,n\in N \text{ }(m>n\ge l\Rightarrow |f_{n+1}(x)+...+f_{m}(x)|<\epsilon)$$

Hence the negation would be:$$\exists \epsilon>0\text{ }\forall l\in N\text{ }\exists x\in D\text{ }\exists m,n\in N \text{ }(m>n\ge l\land |f_{n+1}(x)+...+f_{m}(x)|\ge\epsilon)$$

For the question, I have taken $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\forall l\in N$ let $ x_l=\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{l+1}}$ and $m=l+1,n=l$.

Hence,$$|f_{n+1}(x)+...+f_{m}(x)|=|f_{l+1}(x)|=|\frac{1}{2}|\ge\epsilon)$$

I know that the sum is a geometric sum and it could be shown not to converge uniformly using the fact that $\forall n\in N$ the partial sums of $ x^n$ are bounded on (-1,1).

However, using Cauchy's criterion is the above method correct?

Comment: The logic is correct. You get a little confused in your symbols. In particular, in your statement of the Cauchy Criterion and its negation, you use $l$, but in your proof, you use $n$ for the same role. You should pick one or the other (and then let the other take the place of $z$, so you aren't forcing your readers to confirm that you really are using it in an non-traditional role).

Comment: This approach is correct.